# Windows 10 GameDVR keeps recording while not in-game

Tags: windows-10, screen-capture

I'm using the Xbox Game Bar on my Windows 10 (2004) to record clips of my gameplay. Everything works fine, I have Capture settings to keep record of the last 1 minute, highest audio quality, 60 fps, high video quality.

My problem is, the service stays on and keep recording the last 1 minute while I'm just in Windows, and no game is running. I can bring up the Game Bar overlay and hit "Record last minute" and it will happily save what I was doing in Windows.

This service should only be doing anything when I have an actual game running. Is this a known issue, or can I somehow configure it to launch/start recording when a game is launched?

Also the "GameDVR and Broadcast User Service" is constantly using 10%+ GPU for Video Encode when I'm not even playing. I have Nvidia RTX 2070 Super with latest drivers (446.14) without GeForce Experience.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is, the service stays on and keep recording the last 1 minute while I'm just in Windows, and no game is running. I can bring up the Game Bar overlay and hit "Record last minute" and it will happily save what I was doing in Windows.

Broadly speaking, Game Bar has had the ability to record applications other than games for quite some time.

> This service should only be doing anything when I have an actual game running. Is this a known issue, or can I somehow configure it to launch/start recording when a game is launched?

You can turn background recording on or off manually, but I an not aware of a way to associate it with only certain programs (i.e. games).

> Also the "GameDVR and Broadcast User Service" is constantly using 10%+ GPU for Video Encode when I'm not even playing.

This is likely related to the constant capturing feature your PC seems to be using.